# How can I change similar colors at once?

Tags: colors, gimp, color-palette

I have a bitmap like this [image]

I now need the same button but a red one. Can I apply some tool in the Gimp so all the colors get converted to 'corresponding' shadows of red?

Comment: I'm answering your question, but I still feel it doesn't belong on Stackoverflow, so I flagged it for moderator attention for a move elsewhere (perhaps graphicdesign.stackexchange.com? superuser.com?)

Comment: please keep programming questions here, this is for [su]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Colors->Colorize` or `Colors->Hue-Saturation` are your best bets. Adjust the `Hue` slider to change color.